# Randomly find numbers from 1-12 without repeat

Tags: vb.net, random, integer

I have three variable integers, and I have the following code that randomizes their value:

```
Randomize()

    number = Int(Rnd() * 12) + 1
    AssignImagesToSquares()

    number2 = Int(Rnd() * 12) + 1
    AssignImagesToSquares()

    number3 = Int(Rnd() * 12) + 1
    AssignImagesToSquares()
```

And `AssignImagesToSquares` is a `Private Sub` where I use them.
However, the problem that I am facing is that numbers can be repeated. I could not figure out how to do it, but in psuedocode,

```
'Randomize the integer "number"

'Randomize the integer "number2" where number2 <> number

'Randomize the integer "number3" where number3 <> number2 <> number.
```

I thought of maybe using a loop to repeat the process until a match is found but how exactly can that be done?

Answer (score 2):

As a simple solution you could just use a Do..Loop until the numbers do not match, for example

```
    Randomize()

    number = Int(Rnd() * 12) + 1
    AssignImagesToSquares()

    Do
        number2 = Int(Rnd() * 12) + 1
        If number2 <> number Then
            AssignImagesToSquares()
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Do
        number3 = Int(Rnd() * 12) + 1
        If number3 <> number AndAlso number3 <> number2 Then
            AssignImagesToSquares()
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use loops, but alternatively given your situation you could store your values in array, and take values from this array, and as soon as you pick a value from array you remove it. Then you could use it again. Simple code provided (of course it would be better wrapped in a function):

```
     Dim number1, number2, number3 as Integer
     Dim numbers = New Integer() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}

     Dim indx As Integer = Int(Rnd() * numbers.Length)
     number1=numbers(indx)
     Console.WriteLine(number1)
     System.Array.Clear(numbers, indx, 1)

     indx=Int(Rnd() * numbers.Length) 'wrap in function
     number2=numbers(indx)  '
     Console.WriteLine(number2) 'AssignImagesToSquares()
     System.Array.Clear(numbers, indx, 1) '
```

Answer (score 0):

MAYBE a little overkill ;) , but you can extend this for any number of numbers wanted:

```
        Dim temp As New ConcurrentDictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

        Dim count_actual As Integer = 0
        Dim count_wanted As Integer = 3

        Do
            Dim number = Int(Rnd() * 12) + 1            'or whatever random function
            If temp.TryAdd(number, count_actual) Then
                count_actual += 1
            End If
        Loop While count_actual < count_wanted

        Dim yourNumbers = temp.OrderBy(Function(v) v.Value).Select(Of Integer)(Function(v) v.Key).ToArray()
```

Now there are your wanted random different numbers in the yourNumbers array. Just use them.